# How to create an API for EOSIO smart contract action?

Tags: eosio-code

```
// @abi action
    [[eosio::action]]
    void create(name user,string doctor_name,string doctor_contact,string doctor_address,string patient_problem,string patient_description,string patient_solution){

        require_auth( user ); //require auther permission

        record_index datable( _self,_code.value); // Define database object

        datable.emplace( user, [&](report & r){

            r.report_poster = user;
            r.report_id = datable.available_primary_key();
            r.doctor_name = doctor_name;
            r.doctor_contact = doctor_contact;
            r.doctor_address = doctor_address;
            r.patient_problem = patient_problem;
            r.patient_description = patient_description;
            r.patient_solution = patient_solution;
        }); // create data in database
}
```

This is the EOSIO action for which I want to create an API. How do I proceed?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Which programming language/framework are you using for your server?

Comment: i am using eosjs and node.js

Comment: Try to make api by nodejs follow this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm to know about api in nodejs.

Comment: I know that but it did not work

Comment: It works i have tried

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run create action through eosjs, then you need to set your active key what you upload contract.

I think the reason why "it did not work" may following causes.

1) no right to run contract action. your contact action have this statement
"require_auth( user ); "

2) no proper options for eosjs

3) no proper settings for network

BTW, do you run setabi and setcode for this contract?

anyway, if you upload error statement when you try node.js server, it will be helpful to resolve this issue.